# Cordova file-transfer plugin download always yields http status 401 and error code 3

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic to build an app for Android, and when testing from a device, the call I make using the `org.apache.cordova.file-transfer` plugin always yields the same response.

Here's the code used to fire off the download:

```js
    $scope.getFile = function(){
      var filePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "beer.json";
      var uri = encodeURI('https://stormy-sierra-8448.herokuapp.com/api/?q=stones+pale+ale');
      var options = {};
      $cordovaFileTransfer.download(uri, filePath, options, true)
        .then(function(result) {
          $scope.status = result;
          alert('success');
        }, function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }, function (progress) {
          $timeout(function () {
            $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
          })
        });
    }
```

And then the response (from the console)

```js
FileTransferError {
  code: 3,
  source: "https://stormy-sierra-8448.herokuapp.com/api/?q=stones+pale+ale",
  target: "documents/beer.txt",
  http_status: 401,
  body: null…
}
body: nullcode: 3exception: nullhttp_status: 401source: "https://stormy-sierra-8448.herokuapp.com/api/?q=stones+pale+ale"
target: "documents/beer.txt"
__proto__: FileTransferError
```

My environment looks like this:
Cordova v5.0.0
Ionic 1.3.20

I've seen others post that downgrading the plugin made it work, but when I go below the current version I'm using (0.5), the app doesn't build. When I use the newest version (1.0), the app builds, but after it launches, the console says:

`Uncaught module cordova-plugin-file.ProgressEvent not found - cordova.js:59`

The device has a connection and verified with the 'device' plugin.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe downgrade both plugin and cordova version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I bootstrapped Angular to the device ready event in my main index.html file. Once the event fired, I didn't have to worry about plugins not being initialized and ready for use, which I think is one of the reasons the FileTransfer plugin was failing me.

Another thing I did was install and use the `$iconic` command for **everything**. Before, I was mixing `$cordova [cmd]` and `$ionic [cmd]`. Not sure that it really matters, but everything seems to be working properly now.

The bootstrapping logic is below. I personally think this is how every ionic project should be set up from the get-go. Just remember to remove the ng-app from your body tag or wherever you've placed it.

`angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova) {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
        }, false);
    } else {
        angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
    }
});`

Still using the latest versions of Cordova and Ionic. :)

Comment: In the 1st sentence: index.html